# What is the algorithm behind NodeJS cluster?

Tags: node.js, node-cluster

The head is fairly self explanatory :)

Node supports process clustering ([documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)). But in the documentation I failed to see what algorithm does it use to distribute work to workers.

Is it round-robin? PM2 is using round robin afaik.

Comment: The [How It Works](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works) part mentions round-robin, which is used by default, except on Windows. You might also want to check out [cluster.schedulingPolicy](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_schedulingpolicy).

Comment: Thanks... I completely failed to see that part, and i was actually searching for it... Strange... thank you once again

Comment: Converted my comment into a response as suggested by Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [How It Works](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works) part of the documentation, it is mentionned that Cluster uses **round-robin** by default on most platforms (except on Windows).

You might also want to check out [cluster.schedulingPolicy](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_schedulingpolicy) for a list of available policies.

Comment: Not sure who gave you the downwote and why. You did answer my question correctly